# I can't call a method from a class that extends my List interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have a List interface as well as a SLList class that implements List. I have another class, ListIterator, that uses the SLList to instantiate an object like this:

```
List<E> list = new SLList<>();
```

That part is fine. However, when I try to call a method that is only found in the SLList class, I get a compiler error saying that it can't find the method.

Comment: What does this have to do with generics? This looks to be more a problem with calling a method in a child class that does not exist in the parent class.

Comment: Idk, I thought it could have been a generics question, but you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a method from SLList, the declaration of the variable needs to be of the SLList type:

```
SLList<E> list = new SLList<>(); //this is what I mean
```

For the compiler only the declared type matters (the part on the left)

Comment: Exactly.  That method only exists in the SSList class.  Since you are setting it to a List interface that method won't be available.

Comment: you should accept one of the answers that suits you @user5362867

Answer (score 2):

So you are trying to do something like this?

```
List<E> list = new SLList<>();
list.someMethodOnlyInSLList();
```

Well, in the second line the compiler knows only that list is a `List<E>` so you can't call any method present in the implementation, that isn't part of the interface.

I you want to do that you have either

- create a new interface, possibly extending from List which contains that method and use that interface instead of `List`
- Use `SLList<E> list = new SLList<>();` instead